# The best way to measure Node.js event loop cycle time

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cycle, event-loop, libuv

How can I measure Node.js event loop cycle time? Question is not about event loop delay. Time of the first iteration, second, etc.

Thanks.

I've tried this, but don't know if this a true way...

```
const time = process.hrtime();

setTimeout(() => {
  const diff = process.hrtime(time);

  console.log('benchmark took %d nanoseconds', diff[0] * 1e9 + diff[1]);
});
```

Comment: What do you call the "event loop cycle"? Your code only measures the time it took to reach your timeout callback, but you don't know from where in the event loop, and `setTimeout(cb, 0)` is still clamped to 1ms in node, so you'll be far from anything that could be called an "event loop cycle". What is it that you really want to measure. What actions are you planning to take based on that?

Comment: @Kaiido this is a question from an interview. It was very simple: "How we can measure Node.js event loop iteration time"?

Comment: @Kaiido So I think they mean how we can measure time from the 1-st timeouts cb iteration to the second timeout cb iteration.

Comment: ... out of curiosity, an interview for what position? If a potential employer asked me that, I'd probably have locked them up in a 4hrs presentation of why this question makes no sense and why no one but node js event-loop's engineers might ever have to worry about that. Then I'd probably run from there. There are just so many variables that can affect what will be in between the 2 callbacks executions that it makes purely no sense to measure it. And once again, setTimeout is the worst entry point to the event loop wrt time precision, since it has at least a 1ms timeout (a lot of empty cycles)

Comment: @Kaiido You are right. Here is no sense.